# Matlab derivative returns a constant

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, derivative

I defined a function which returns the derivative of either a symbolic expression or a function handle (plus a few more).

```
function df = der(f)
    if isa(f, 'cfit') || isa(f, 'sfit')
        df = @(x) differentiate(f, x);
    elseif isa(f, 'sym') || isa(f, 'function_handle')
        syms r
        F = sym(f);
        df = matlabFunction(diff(F), 'Vars', r);
    else
        error('Not a derivative of a known type')
    end
end
```

It works well however when I feed in a line, I get something which does not produce arrays.

```
>> df = der(@(r) r)

df = 

    @(r)1.0

>> df([1,2,3])

ans =

    1
```

Is there anyway to catch whether the output function is a constant and change the output so the behavior is,

```
>> df = der(@(r) r)

df = 

    @(r)1.0*ones(size(r))

>> df([1,2,3])

ans =

    1 1 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution.

```
function df = der(f)
    if isa(f, 'cfit') || isa(f, 'sfit')
        df = @(x) differentiate(f, x);
    elseif isa(f, 'sym') || isa(f, 'function_handle')
        syms r
        F = sym(f);
        df = matlabFunction(diff(F), 'Vars', r);
    % These next four lines have been added:
        c = df(ones(1,2));             
        if length(c) == 1
            df = @(x) c*ones(size(x));
        end                            
    else
        error('Not a derivative of a known type')
    end
end
```

Evaluating `df = der(@(r) 20*r); df([1,2,3])` now gives the output

```
ans =

    20 20 20
```

Comment: Hi! I've made a MATLAB chat room for us in case you wanted to discuss anything related to MATLAB that is off-topic, or if you want to discuss things that span longer than a comments block.  Stop by when you have time! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab

Answer (score 1):

To explain the error in your code, `syms r` creates a scalar symbolic variable. As far as I am aware, there is no reliable solution to get a vectorized version.

A simple "fix", evaluate each value individually:

```
>> arrayfun(df,[1,2,3])

ans =

     1     1     1
```